# re.sub replace substring between two specific characters multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, python-re

Given a string `s` as follows, I want to remove substring between `but` and `ball` multiple times:

```
s = 'I like sport, but I don\'t like football; I like sport, but I don\'t like basketball'
re.sub('but.*ball', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Out:

```
'I like sport, '
```

How could I get the expected result like this:

```
'I like sport, I like sport'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a question mark:

```
>>> re.sub('but.*?ball|[,;]', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE).strip()
'I like sport  I like sport'
>>>
```

Comment: "If you give a man a fish, you feed him for a day. If you teach a man to fish, you feed him for a lifetime."